# How do I make linux swap more eagerly?

Tags: linux, memory, swap

I have a use-case where I have bursts of allocations in the range of 5-6gb, specifically when Visual Studio Code compiles my D project while I'm typing. (The compiler doesn't release memory at all, in order to be as fast as possible.)

> DMD does memory allocation in a bit of a sneaky way. Since compilers are short-lived programs, and speed is of the essence, DMD just mallocs away, and never frees. This eliminates the scaffolding and complexity of figuring out who owns the memory and when it should be released. (It has the downside of consuming all the resources of your machine if the module being compiled is big enough.)

[source](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/increasing-compiler-speed-by-over-75/240158941)

The machine is a Dell XPS 13 running Manjaro 64-bit, with 16gb of memory -- and I'm hitting that roof. The system seizes up completely, REISUB may or may not work, etc. I can leave it for an hour and it's still hung, not slowly resolving itself. The times I've been able to get to a tty, dmesg has had all kinds of jovial messages. So I thought to enable a big swap partition to alleviate the pressure, but it isn't helping.

I realise that swap won't be used until it's needed, but by then it's too late. Even with the swap, when I run out of memory everything segfaults; Qt, zsh, fuse-ntfs, Xorg. At that point it will report a typical 70mb of swap in use.

`vm.swappiness` is at 100. swapon reports the swap as being active, automatically enabled by systemd.

```
NAME           TYPE       SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/nvme0n1p8 partition 17.6G   0B   -2
```

What can I do to make it swap *more*?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You don't need to adjust swappiness, and there's no such thing as it being "too late" to swap. Sounds like something else. If processes really are segfaulting and not being oom killed, you should re-enable overcommit. Also consider checking for bad ram.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remember to put this question in superuser or serverfault. Stackoverflow is only for programming stuff.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/371302/make-my-ubuntu-use-more-swap-than-ram